# Angular piple shortDate doesnt work probably for year 2022

Tags: angular

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.
I am using Angular 5.
For the following pipe should date for year 2023 it is ok?

```
{{value | shortDate}}
```

See image below:
[image]

But for any date in year 2022 it shows like this:
[image]

Date Picker code:

```
    <date-picker #dataPicker 
            *ngIf="showDatePicker && !readOnly && inEditing"
            [(ngModel)]="value"
            [inputNoBorder]="false"
            [minDate]="minDate"
            [maxDate]="maxDate"
            [mandatory]="mandatory"
            [showTrashWhenEmpty]="showTrashWhenEmpty" 
            (onSelect)="onChangeDate($event)"
            (onBlurChange)="onBlurChange($event)"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (validDate)="isValidDate($event)">
            </date-picker>
```

It is missing year and it should be 08/Aug/22?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of Angular 5](https://v5.angular.io/api/common/DatePipe), the date pipe should be used like this:

```
    {{ value | date:'shortDate' }}
```

And `value` should be a Date object. Depending on the lib you're using, the `date-picker` component may not be creating a date object.